# Changing Bucket from Multi-Region to Single region

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Currently we have buckets which are set to multi-region but this can be regional. Is there a way we can change it in Google Cloud Bucket settings (or) should I create a new regional bucket and move the data ? any links to Google documentation will be great.

Comment: There is no one-step solution for changing buckets from being multi-regional to regional.yes you have to create a new regional bucket and move the data as in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4ZLJiL4INs)

Comment: Why do you want to move from multi-region to region?

Comment: Multi region costs more compared with single region. Our use case is ok with single region

Comment: for moving and renaming the bucket check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets) which might help you